Content builder - Formatting numbers of different lengths to show in different ways
Using content builder to create emails, and pulling numbers in from a data extension.
Some are 9 digits and some are 10 digits.
Using 'format number' to show spaces between some of the digits so they show as either "### ### ###" or "### #### ###".
So I would always like to lead with a group of three digits.
I've used the following %%=formatnumber(@telNo,"### ### ###")=%% but in instances where there are 10 digits the extra digit always shows in that first group, so it returns "#### ### ###".
If I try %%=formatnumber(@telNo,"### #### ###")=%%, to add that extra digit to the middle group, when it's only 9 digits it returns "## #### ###".
Any potential solutions would be appreciated.

You can handle this by putting a check condition to find out if the tel number has 9 digits or 10 digits then have a proper format for it.
Try it yourself:
%%[
    set @telNo = 123456789
    /* set @telNo = 2987654321 */

    if Length(@telNo) == 9 then
        set @formatedNo = Format(@telNo, "### ### ###")
    else
        set @formatedNo = Format(@telNo, "### #### ###")
    endif
]%%
%%=v(@formatedNo)=%%

